# Armstrong Numbers Bufferoverflow

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

Currently I am trying to build a program that prints all armstrongnumbers till a certain number. I am getting some odd error when trying to run this. It says bufferoverflow.
The part causing it seems to be in main(). Thanks for any help.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXIMUM 1000000

int ipow(int x, int power){ 
int z,t;
t = 0;
z = x;
for (t = 0; t < (power - 1); t++) {
    z = z * x; }
return z;
}


int getLength(int x) { 
    int a;
    a = 1;
    for (a=1;1;a++) { if (x < ipow(10,a) && x >= ipow(10,(a-1))) return a; }
}

int getExpSum(int x) { 
    int summe,r,s,t;
    int digit[8]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    summe=0;
    s = getLength(x);
    t = x;
    r = 1;
    for (s=getLength(x);s!=0;s--){
        digit[s] = t % 10;
        t = t / 10;
    }
    for(r=1;r<(getLength(x)+1);r++)
    {
        summe = summe + ipow(digit[r],getLength(x));
    }
    return summe;
}

int Armstrong (int x) {
    if (getExpSum(x)==x) {
        printf("%d ist eine Armstrongzahl\n", x);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void main(){
    int z;
    z = 0;
    for (z=0;z<MAXIMUM;z++){
        Armstrong(z+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (a=1;a=a;a++)` tricky and with no benefit.

Comment: @user1803470: `for (a = 1; ; ++a)`. Or `for (a = 1; 1; ++a)` if you don't like the look of the empty condition, but some compilers will give you a warning for that.

Comment: Changed it to 1. Thank you. The main error is still there tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in your "getLength" Function (actually ipow)

pass getLength(1) and you get result as 13 because 
ipow(10, 1) and ipow(10, 0) returns 10 so the "getLength" condition fails and it goes for next iteration and goes on.. until the ipow returns a negative number thats 10^13 because of the integer size.

And inside getExpSum the array digit is of size 8 and it tries to acces the 13th element of it. Hence it crashes

Add the condition to the ipow function

```
int ipow(int x, int power){ 
int z,t;
t = 0;
z = x;
 if (power == 0) //<-----add this condition to your code
     return 1;

for (t = 0; t < (power - 1); t++) {
    z = z * x; }
return z;
}
```

After adding this condition I get the correct result.

```
1 ist eine Armstrongzahl
2 ist eine Armstrongzahl
3 ist eine Armstrongzahl
4 ist eine Armstrongzahl
5 ist eine Armstrongzahl
6 ist eine Armstrongzahl
7 ist eine Armstrongzahl
8 ist eine Armstrongzahl
9 ist eine Armstrongzahl
153 ist eine Armstrongzahl
370 ist eine Armstrongzahl
371 ist eine Armstrongzahl
407 ist eine Armstrongzahl
1634 ist eine Armstrongzahl
8208 ist eine Armstrongzahl
9474 ist eine Armstrongzahl
54748 ist eine Armstrongzahl
92727 ist eine Armstrongzahl
93084 ist eine Armstrongzahl
548834 ist eine Armstrongzahl
```

BTW the solution can be improved.

Comment: Yes it probably can be done. However I just started learning C not long ago and therefore I am happy if I get a working solution at all. Thank you!